# Apache Flume (twitter)

Tags: twitter, flume

I am a beginner so kindly bear with me. I need to download twitter logs and would like to use Flume. However, I am not familiar with Java. Can Python be use with the Flume Agent ? Any links that I could refer to will be very helpful.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to code anything but properly configure Flume with already developed stuff ;)

Please, refer to [this](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html) link. I followed it some time ago in order to capture certain twits into my HDFS. If any question with the details, I can help you based on my own experience with such a link.